# Python OOP related to usage of instance variables

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, class, oop, instance-variables

```
class idk():
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def t(self):
        self.t = self.name + self.age
    def qrt(self):
        print(len(self.t))                             

abc = idk('abc','19')                 
abc.qrt()

abc.name= 'aduhd'            
abc.qrt()
```

When i run this code i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Prajval/Desktop/test.py", line 11, in <module>
        abc.qrt()
    File "C:/Users/Prajval/Desktop/test.py", line 8, in qrt
        print(len(self.t))
TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()
```

what does the following error mean:

> TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()

Comment: It gives the error because variable 't' does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call the method, which you have given the same name `t` as an instance variable.

```
def qrt(self):
    print(len(self.t()))
```

By naming a method the same as an instance variable you are playing with fire. First time when you call the `t` method, it would behave as a method, and as a string post first call. Don't dug a hole for yourself to fall in.

Answer (score 1):

Final code,

```
class idk():
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        
    def t(self):
        self.t1 = self.name + self.age
        return self. t1 # was missing 
        
    def qrt(self):
        print(len(self.t()))                             

abc = idk('abc','19')                 
abc.qrt()

abc.name= 'aduhd'            
abc.qrt()
```

```
5
7

[Program finished]
```